# How can I get all the style information about .innerText

Tags: javascript

```
    var Before= stuff2[0].innerText;
```

```
Then I call (Before)
```

Html info, I want to grab the style info

```
<a href="/game/1679819" style="color: rgb(255, 90, 95);">1.09x</a>
```

I get the following response
 `"3.07x  4.38x   15.33x  1.07x   9.93x   1.04x   6.25x"`

Comment: have you tried innerHTML?

Comment: Have you tried `.innerHTML`?

Comment: LOL OMG I'm dumb.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianSpeitel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.innerHTML` to get the HTML and related styles where as `.innerText` gets just the text.

Comment: For some reason javascript is changing res2's value in my if statement